# Can we consider AWS RDS read replica as Backup?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have postgres on rds with 2 day snapshot retention. But it's only updated daily so in order not to lose 24 hours of data, I decided to enable read replica to make sure data are safe.

Is it okay to use read replica as backup?

Is there any better way to have sync backup (maximum 30 mins lag) of postgres from rds?

Answer (score 4):

RDS Postgres supports point-in-time restores (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html).

If you run a disastrous query on your main database, your read replica will also sync this changes. Don#t use it as a backup.

Comment: point in time as in any point during the retention period? so i do not have to worry about rds doing just daily backup right?

Comment: that's right. I recommend to retain more than 2 days. better 14

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we don't need to backup manually.

[DB Instance Backups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html)

> RDS provide daily automated backups, Amazon RDS also archives database change
>   logs. This enables you to recover your database to any point in time
>   during the backup retention period, up to the last five minutes of
>   database usage. For more information on working with point-in-time
>   recovery, see [Restoring a DB Instance to a Specified Time](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html).

Hola !!

Comment: Does it mean I do not need to have external backup? just use aws point in time?

Comment: exactly !! Read doc.